# PostgreSQL nextval and currval in same query

Tags: postgresql

I was hoping to call `NEXTVAL` once and use the returned values multiple times. However it doesn't work.

Assume the sequence `seq_name` is at 10 now (*queries are executed independently, not in listed order*):

```
SELECT NEXTVAL('seq_name'), NEXTVAL('seq_name');
```

The above will give 11, 12 (I want 11 and 11 again).

```
SELECT NEXTVAL('seq_name'), CURRVAL('seq_name');
SELECT NEXTVAL('seq_name'), LASTVAL();
```

The above will give 11, 10 **OR** give an error that `NEXTVAL` was never called in the current session. [ *I know why the error happens :)* ]

Is there a way to use `NEXTVAL` and `CURRVAL` in the same SQL statement to get the same incremented value (11 in this case) for reuse? Or a simple solution to this problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A possible solution

```
SELECT nextval nextval1, nextval nextval2
  FROM
(
  SELECT NEXTVAL('seq_name') nextval
) q
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/89cc3/4)** demo.

**UPDATE** To insert instead of `INSERT INTO ... VALUES` use `INSERT INTO ... SELECT`

```
INSERT INTO Table1 (col1, col2, col3, col4, ...) 
SELECT nextval, nextval, 5, 'Text value', ...
  FROM
(
  SELECT NEXTVAL('seq_name') nextval
) q
```

Comment: How about an `INSERT () VALUES ()` construct? I need it for such an insert statement, therefore a more general solution would be apt. Your solution is too specific to SELECT statements.

Comment: Thanks, nice answer, but what if I really _really_ ***really*** have to stick to the INSERT VALUES construct? :D

Comment: There is no situation (at least I'm not aware of) when you can't replace `INSERT VALUES` with `INSERT SELECT` :)

Comment: Otherwise wrap it into a procedure and use a variable

Comment: You're right, and I agree. But it's a challenge, right? :) Btw, don't try it in SQLFiddle.. for some reason the NEXTVAL and CURRVAL in same insert statement returns the same value (it doesn't work that way in the DB I use... maybe different version? IDK...).